PowerShell Script to List Azure DevOps Users with Direct Assignments Not Returning Expected Results
I'm trying to write a PowerShell script to list all users with direct assignments in Azure DevOps, excluding certain technical accounts. The script should also retrieve their managers' email addresses from Azure AD. However, the script isn't returning the expected results.
What I'm Trying to Achieve:

Fetch users with direct assignments (assignmentSource equals "direct") in Azure DevOps.
Exclude specific users (technical accounts) from the list.
Retrieve each user's manager's email address from Azure AD.
Output the list of user email addresses and
their managers.

My Current Script:
# Variables
$organization = "org-name"
$azureDevOpsPat = "your-azure-devops-pat"  # PAT with full access
$tenantId = "your-tenant-id"
$clientId = "your-client-id"
$excludedUsers = @(
    "example1@org.com",
    "example2@org.com",
    "example3@org.com"

)

# Scopes for Microsoft Graph
$scopes = @("User.Read.All", "Directory.Read.All")

# Connect to Microsoft Graph
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -Scopes $scopes -DeviceCode

# Azure DevOps API Endpoint
$devOpsApiUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.0"

# Prepare Azure DevOps API Headers
$devOpsHeaders = @{
    Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$azureDevOpsPat")))
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Fetch user entitlements from Azure DevOps
$devOpsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $devOpsApiUrl -Headers $devOpsHeaders -Method Get

# Check if the response contains any users
if ($devOpsResponse.count -gt 0) {
    # Include all users with direct assignments
    $directUsers = $devOpsResponse.value | Where-Object {
        $_.accessLevel.assignmentSource -eq "direct"
    }

    foreach ($user in $directUsers) {
        $userEmail = $user.user.mailAddress
        $userPrincipalName = $user.user.principalName

        # Get user identifier for exclusion check (UPN or Email)
        $userIdentifier = if ($userPrincipalName) { $userPrincipalName } else { $userEmail }

        # Check if the user is in the exclusion list
        if ($excludedUsers -contains $userIdentifier) {
            continue
        }

        # Get user details from Microsoft Graph API
        try {
            $userGraphResponse = Get-MgUser -UserId $userIdentifier -ErrorAction Stop
            $userEmail = $userGraphResponse.Mail

            # Get manager's information
            try {
                $managerResponse = Get-MgUserManager -UserId $userIdentifier -ErrorAction Stop
                $managerUpn = $managerResponse.UserPrincipalName
            } catch {
                $managerUpn = $null
            }
        } catch {
            continue
        }

        # Collect email addresses
        if ($userEmail) {
            $userEmailAddresses += $userEmail
        }

        if ($managerUpn) {
            $managerEmailAddresses += $managerUpn
        }
    }

    # Output the lists
    $userEmailsString = $userEmailAddresses -join "; "
    $managerEmailsString = $managerEmailAddresses -join "; "

    Write-Host "User Emails (To): $userEmailsString"
    Write-Host "Manager Emails (CC): $managerEmailsString"
} else {
    Write-Host "No user entitlements found in Azure DevOps."
}

# Disconnect from Microsoft Graph
Disconnect-MgGraph

The Issue:
When I run the script, it returns Found 0 users with direct assignments, even though I know there are users with direct assignments in Azure DevOps.
Manually invoking the Azure DevOps API returns only my own user entitlement, and $directUsers.Count is 0.
Additional Information:
I'm running PowerShell on macOS.
Using the latest version of the Microsoft.Graph module.
Have the necessary permissions in Azure AD (tenant owner) to read user information.

Could you confirm whether you are getting any results when you run the script locally?

Yes, when I run the script locally, I get the following output: Connected to Microsoft Graph as my-account@mycompany
Fetching user entitlements from Azure DevOps...
Found 0 users with direct assignments.
User Email Addresses:

Manager Email Addresses:

All Email Addresses:

Copy the following lists into Outlook:
User Emails (To):
Manager Emails (CC):
All Emails (To/CC):

There are several errors in your scripts.

According to REST API User Entitlements - List,


The supported values of AssignmentSource are groupRule, none and unknown. To get the user whose assignment source is direct, you should use $_.accessLevel.assignmentSource -eq "unknown"


According to Get-MgUser,


The UserId is the object id of the user in AAD, you can't use UPN or Email as input. Use UPN as a filter instead. For example, $userGraphResponse = Get-MgUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userIdentifier'" -ErrorAction Stop.
Get the id of the user via $userId = $userGraphResponse.Id, which will be used later.


According to Get-MgUserManager,


UserId is the object id, use $userId as input to get the info about this user's manager.
There isn't such parameter $managerResponse.UserPrincipalName in the response of Get-MgUserManager. Run Get-MgUserManager first to get the id of the manager, and then run Get-MgUser to get the mail of this manager.

Below are the modified scripts for your reference.
# Variables
$organization = "{DevOps Org}"
$azureDevOpsPat = "{PAT}"  # PAT with full access
$tenantId = "{tenant id}"
$clientId = "{client id}"
$clientSecret = "{client secret}"
$secureClientSecret = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($clientId, $secureClientSecret)

$excludedUsers = @(
    "example1@org.com",
    "example2@org.com",
    "example3@org.com"
)

# Scopes for Microsoft Graph
$scopes = @("User.Read.All", "Directory.Read.All")

# Connect to Microsoft Graph
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $tenantId -ClientSecretCredential $credential

# Azure DevOps API Endpoint
$devOpsApiUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/userentitlements?top=2000&api-version=4.1-preview.1"

# Prepare Azure DevOps API Headers
$devOpsHeaders = @{
    Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$azureDevOpsPat")))
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Fetch user entitlements from Azure DevOps
$devOpsResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $devOpsApiUrl -Headers $devOpsHeaders -Method Get
# Write-Host "Fetched user entitlements: $($devOpsResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3)"

# Check if the response contains any users
if ($devOpsResponse.count -gt 0) {
    # Include all users with direct assignments
    $directUsers = $devOpsResponse.value | Where-Object {
        $_.accessLevel.assignmentSource -eq "unknown"
    }
    # $directUsers | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_ }

    foreach ($user in $directUsers) {
        # Write-Host "user: $($user | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3)"
        $userEmail = $user.user.mailAddress
        $userPrincipalName = $user.user.principalName


        # Get user identifier for exclusion check (UPN or Email)
        $userIdentifier = if ($userPrincipalName) { $userPrincipalName } else { $userEmail }
        # Write-Host $userIdentifier

        # Check if the user is in the exclusion list
        if ($excludedUsers -contains $userIdentifier) {
            # Write-Host "$($userIdentifier) is in the excluded list"
            continue
        }

        # Get user details from Microsoft Graph API
        try {
            $userGraphResponse = Get-MgUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$userIdentifier'" -ErrorAction Stop
            # Write-Host "userGraphResponse: $($userGraphResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3)"
            $userId = $userGraphResponse.Id
            $userEmail = $userGraphResponse.Mail
            Write-Host $userId 
            Write-Host $userEmail

            # Get manager's information
            try {
                $managerResponse = Get-MgUserManager -UserId $userId -ErrorAction Stop
                # Write-Host "managerResponse: $($managerResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3)"
                $managerId= $managerResponse.Id
                $manager = Get-MgUser -UserId $managerId
                $managerMail = $manager.Mail
                # Write-Host "managerMail is $($managerMail)"
            } catch {
                $managerMail = $null
            }
        } catch {
            continue
        }

        # Collect email addresses
        if ($userEmail) {
            $userEmailsString += $userEmail + ";"
        }

        if ($managerMail) {
            $managerEmailsString += $managerMail + ";"
        }
    }

    # Output the lists
    Write-Host "User Emails (To): $userEmailsString"
    Write-Host "Manager Emails (CC): $managerEmailsString"

} else {
    Write-Host "No user entitlements found in Azure DevOps."
}

# Disconnect from Microsoft Graph
Disconnect-MgGraph

Result:


thank you for the suggestions!  Visual Studio Code shows me one problem, namely : The variable 'scopes' is assigned but never used. I run the script and still no results, I am wondering maybe the scopes variable is the cause now

Did you run the same scripts shared by me? It works fine from my side. - "Visual Studio Code shows me one problem, namely : The variable 'scopes' is assigned but never used." This isn't related to the issue. I don't pass $scopes to Connect-MgGraph and it will have the expected result if I pass it to Connect-MgGraph. Currently, you don't get any result from Azure DevOps REST API User Entitlements - List, but -scope is used for connecting to Azure Tenant, so that it has nothing to do with his issue.

What's your permission in Azure DevOps? Is your account a PCA? You can add some Write-Host commands to help check which commands don't have the expected result in your situation. You can refer to the comment lines in my scripts.

Yes, I am a project collection administrator ad org level and I use the same script. Very strange, I will add some debugging.

Can you have a try to run the above scripts in a PowerShell task in Azure pipeline and using image windows-2022? Don't forget to create a secret for your client app in AAD.

I run the script with an azure pipeline with windows-2022 but still the output is emtpy User Emails (To):
Manager Emails (CC):
I will use the Write-Host commands from your script to check the cause

I add more Write-Host command in my scripts above to help your check which step doesn't return the expected values.

Seems like the first write-host check :  "Fetched user entitlements: $($devOpsResponse | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3)" returns only some of the users with group rule assignment. So not just that no user with direct/unknown user is returned, moreover not all users with group rule assignment are returned

Please open your browser and access your organization. Then copy and paste https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{Org Name}/_apis/userentitlements?top=2000&api-version=7.0 directly to your browser and check what's the result. Besides, may I know how many users in your organization?

In my organization I have more than 500. The API https://vsaex.dev.azure.com//_apis/userentitlements?top=2000&api-version=7.0 returns 196 users. From this 196 users 4 have "assignmentSource": "unknown" and the other have "assignmentSource": "groupRule". The users with direct assignment are over 40

"In my organization I have more than 500" - Can you double check if there are more than 500 users in your organization? If you check the user list from Organization settings, service principles and managed identities are also in the list by default. But this API doesn't return info related to SP and MI.

In Org Settings - Users - All Users , when I filter out the Application Service Principals and Managed Identity I have no results : " No users match your filter ", so I guess all users members

Can you try the API again with version 4.1-preview.1? https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/userentitlements?top=2000&api-version=4.1-preview.1? See the details from this doc.

Using 4.1 API version shows correctly all users. I see that the users have either "assignmentSource": "unknown" or "assignmentSource": "groupRule". There is no "direct" property or any other third type of assignmentSource. I noticed that you have updated your Script in Answer : # Azure DevOps API Endpoint
$devOpsApiUrl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/userentitlements?top=2000&api-version=4.1-preview.1".  However, when I run it I get : No user entitlements found in Azure DevOps.

Hi @My ADO Obsession, as I mentioned "The supported values of AssignmentSource are groupRule, none and unknown. To get the user whose assignment source is direct, you should use $_.accessLevel.assignmentSource -eq "unknown"".

I found that the above script worked for me but not for you because my organization has less than 100 people. The return values ​​of the 7.0 version of the API and the 4.1-preview.1 version of the API are slightly different. I have made corresponding changes to my scripts, please try the latest scripts again.

I run the above script again, I still get no results for the fields "User Emails To : Manager Emails to: " I uncommented the Write-Host "Fetched user entitlements and I get an output of 32 users, 27 with group rule and 5 with unknown

Have you included top=2000 in the URL? Since you can get all users when using 4.1-preview.1 version, you should be able to get the same result in the PowerShell scripts. Try to run GET https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/_apis/userentitlements?top=2000&api-version=4.1-preview.1 in a separate PowerShell script and check what's the result.

I run a script that contains the following steps, and it returned the correct number of users
Initialize variables for pagination
$allUsers = @() $continuationToken = $null do { $apiUrl = "vsaex.dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/…" if ($continuationToken) { $apiUrl += "&continuationToken=$continuationToken" }.   # Invoke API
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $devOpsHeaders -Method Get

continuationToken is used for REST API which version greater than 4.1-preview.1. For version 4.1-preview.1, you need to add top in the request header. I am guessing that you are using top in version greater than 4.1-preview.1, so that the above scripts don't return all users. You can choose to use top with version 4.1-preview.1 or use continuationToken` with greater version, for example, 7.0. Then it should work as expected.

my main script uses $top and 4.1-preview.1 version, which should work together , but still I do not get the expected output

Which step are you not getting the expected data in? Is it "Fetch user entitlements from Azure DevOps" or somewhere else?

I managed to obtain an output with all users and their managers but are returned as  bulk, I need a solution now to map each user with his manager from Entra in the output. I will open a new Question for that, thank you for your help
